# angularjs fetch app data firstly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I got couple of views in my application & **I'd like to let user switch between this views without delay due to fetching data from backend server.**
Required data are defined in $routeProvider. **How in elegant way can I delivery solution which will fetch data from server after angular load and keep this data available for $routeProvider?**

My ideas doesn't work because:

1. I could put code in some main controller but *$scope isn't available in $routeProvider;*
2. I could put code fetching data in some Factory class like this:

```
APP.factory('DataFactory', function($q,KAS){
return {
    data:new Array(),
    fetchData:function(){
        var albums=$q.defer();
        var artists=$q.defer();
        var genres=$q.defer();

        albums.resolve(KAS.api({action:'get_albums'}));
        artists.resolve(KAS.api({action:'get_artists'}));
        genres.resolve(KAS.api({action:'get_genres'}));

        var data=$q.all([albums.promise, artists.promise, genres.promise]);
        data.then(function(retv){
            angular.forEach(retv, function(value, key){
                data[key]=(value.data.response);
            });
        });
    },
    getData:function(){
        return data;
    }
}
});
```

but getData function havn't got access to data array - I cant refer to data property. Actually it's obvious because Im returning array of functions/objects. but I pasted it above for understanding what I actully want to do.

**How in elegant way can I delivery solution which will fetch data from server after angular load and keep this data available for $routeProvider?**

Answer (score 0):

You are creating variables (`var data`) instead of assigning to object's properties. JavaScript thinks that you are using a variable named data, but in reality you are refering to the property data of the object that you are returning.

```
APP.factory('DataFactory', function($q,KAS){
    var myFactory = {
        data:new Array(),
        fetchData:function(){
            var albums=$q.defer();
            var artists=$q.defer();
            var genres=$q.defer();

            albums.resolve(KAS.api({action:'get_albums'}));
            artists.resolve(KAS.api({action:'get_artists'}));
            genres.resolve(KAS.api({action:'get_genres'}));

            myFactory.data = $q.all([albums.promise, artists.promise, genres.promise]);
            myFactory.data.then(function(retv){
                angular.forEach(retv, function(value, key){
                    this.data[key]=(value.data.response);
                });
            });
        },
        getData:function(){
            return myFactory.data;
        }
    };
    return myFactory;
});
```

Comment: yes you're right but actually it dosent fix the problem